# Custom Set Class (based off STL Set) Sorted Insert Issues

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, iterator, set

I am supposed to create a custom **Set** class based off Set from the STL. In addition we are to use a custom Iterator class: **SetIterator**. A requirement is to keep the set sorted. I'm having trouble getting my insert method to work correctly. I am still new to iterators and working with dynamically allocated arrays....

Solved

Comment: If you're just asking us to help improve working code, especially if your problem is just that it's "not very efficient", I think that's a better question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for StackOverflow. If you have a specific problem that you're stuck on, that's a different story… but in that case, what is your question?

Comment: Anyway, there's definitely a better way to do a set than to keep a sorted array and shift everything around. If you're supposed to be "based off STL set", it uses a red-black tree, which allows insertions to be done in logarithmic rather than linear time.

Comment: To clarify by "based off STL set" I mean that is has an insert, find, erase, etc... But my question is where am I messing up on the sort? It's adding the items to the set but when it sorts them an item gets cut out (see sample run at end of main post). If I enter "2, 4, 1" the set should hold it as: "1, 2, 4" yet I get either "1, 4, 4" or "1, 4, -826374" (random value outside the index) depending on my implementation.

Comment: (it +1) is not an lvalue, does this code compile?

Comment: OK, then what do you mean by "a better way"? From earlier in your question, it sounds like what you're "really not happy with" is performance. If so, then you really do need to start over and use an appropriate data structure under the covers. If not, then what _are_ you asking for? If it's just how to fix a bug, why are you asking for "a better way" in the first place?

Comment: SetIterator overloads ++, --, -, and + to shift the pointer forward or back. So (it + 1) shifts the pointer. SetIterator is a template class containing a member variable T * p. The code does compile. What I'm asking for is how exactly do I do this? Disregard "a better way". I was just referring to the fact I keep adding things here and there to the function fixing each little problem that leads to another. I'm going to post above some pseudocode for the algorithm I was supposed to be using and come far from. Sorry for any confusion, thanks!